# Espresso idlingResource - how to change how frequent the check for idling occurs

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I am showing a few loading dialogs. they sort of flash because of different network calls so there are times my idling resource will report that is it idle now but really the loading dialog just got dismissed by one network call but then triggered again by another network call.  Lets take a look my resource:

```
public class LoadingDialogIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
    private final FragmentManager manager;
    private final String tag;
    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    public LoadingDialogIdlingResource(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return LoadingDialogIdlingResource.class.getName() + ":" + tag;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
      //this is being called to quickly, i want to slow it down without suspending the entire thread
        manager.executePendingTransactions();
        boolean idle = (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null);
        Timber.d("check if idle:" + idle);

        if (idle) {
            resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }
        return idle;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }
}
```

here is what i have tried so far:

```
IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(45000L,TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
```

but this is not what i want this is the timeout for the system. i just want to slow down how often the system checks if its idleNow by a second. So to be clear, im looking for a way to slow down the check in isIdleNow() method.

Comment: Would putting @UiThread annotation on "isIdleNow" method do anything since "executePendingTransaction" should run on UI thread?

Comment: The "standard" way of pausing execution on a thread is to use "Thread.sleep(n)" where n is the number of milliseconds to pause.  Not something you should do in the production app some consider it ok in testing.

Comment: There should be a policy configuration for this.